# I am not able to install arduino 1.8.2

Tags: command-line, software-installation, arduino

When I run the command `./install.sh` in the terminal it displays

```
cc.arduino.arduinonoide does not exist
xdg-icon-resource: icon name 'cc.arduino.arduinonoide' does not have a proper vendor prefix
```

[image: please take a look at the screenshot and help me out i would be really very greatful]

Comment: It may be that the resource name in the install.sh file is wrong.  Is there a file named `arduino-arduinoide.xml` in the Arduino-1.8.2 64/lib?

Comment: yes sir there is a file named arduino-arduinoide.xml

Comment: In that case, the answer I posted below should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well.  It looks to be a file-naming error in the script.

When I looked in `Arduino-1.8.2 64/lib` there was no file `cc.arduino.arduinonoide.xml`  but there was a file named `arduino-arduinonoide.xml`

I opened `install.sh` in the editor and changed `RESOURCE_NAME=cc.arduino.arduinoide` to `RESOURCE_NAME=arduino-arduinoide` and saved the changes.

When I re-ran `./install.sh` in the terminal it ran without a hitch.

By the way, to make your like easier in future, I'd also move the `Arduino-1.8.2 64` folder to the  `/opt/` directory before installing. So run the following sequence of commands:

Navigate to your downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

edit the `install.sh` script as described above to correct the problem with RESOURCE_NAME:

```
cd arduino-1.8.2 64
nano install.sh
```

Make the changes as explained above, then save and exit.

Move the installation folder and then navigate to the new folder:

```
cd ..
sudo mv arduino-1.8.2 64 /opt
cd /opt/arduino-1.8.2 64/
```

Make `install.sh` executable:

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

and then run the script:

```
./install.sh
```

The Arduino IDE should now be installed and you should see the icon on your desktop.

---

UPDATE: I posted about this error on the Arduino forum.  It seems this was a known issue and will be [fixed in release 1.8.3](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/6110)

Comment: @PavanVaryani instead of commenting "thanks", please consider [accepting this answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).